# Access Query - Invalid Operation when using Order By clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

The following query works fine but as soon as I add the `Order By` clause, I get an

> error - "invalid operation"

Can any one help me please?

```
SELECT dbo_jobs.jobid,
       dbo_jobs.jobrefno,
       dbo_jobs.createdon,
       dbo_jobs.archived,
       dbo_jobs.published,
       dbo_jobs.jobtitle,
       dbo_jobs.statusid,
       dbo_jobs.clientid,
       dbo_clients.company,
       dbo_clientcontacts.clientcontactid,
       dbo_employmenttypes.employmenttypeid,
       dbo_employmenttypes.description,
       dbo_locations.description,
       dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.clientname,
       dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.natureofcase,
       dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.timescaletodeadline,
       dbo_jobs.notes,
       dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.status,
       dbo_clientcontacts.contactpersonid,
       dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.vat,
       dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.postcode,
       dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.additionalinfo,
       dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.solicitorref,
       dbo_jobconsultants.userid,
       dbo_users.loginname,
       dbo_jobs.positionattributeid,
       dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.consultancyservice,
       [dbo_person].[PersonName] & ' ' & [dbo_person].[Surname] AS ClientCon,
       dbo_person.personname,
       dbo_person.surname,
       dbo_jobstatus.description,
       dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.priority,
       RevListCount.countofrevids,
       CVCount.cvsentcount
FROM   (((SELECT dbo_jobs.jobid,
                dbo_jobs.jobrefno,
                dbo_jobs.createdon,
                dbo_jobs.archived,
                dbo_jobs.published,
                dbo_jobs.jobtitle,
                dbo_jobs.statusid,
                dbo_jobs.clientid,
                dbo_clients.company,
                dbo_clientcontacts.clientcontactid,
                dbo_employmenttypes.employmenttypeid,
                dbo_employmenttypes.description,
                dbo_locations.description,
                dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.clientname,
                dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.natureofcase,
                dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.timescaletodeadline,
                dbo_jobs.notes,
                dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.status,
                dbo_clientcontacts.contactpersonid,
                dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.vat,
                dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.postcode,
                dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.additionalinfo,
                dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.solicitorref,
                dbo_jobconsultants.userid,
                dbo_users.loginname,
                dbo_jobs.positionattributeid,
                dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.consultancyservice,
                [dbo_person].[personname] & ' ' & [dbo_person].[surname] AS
                 ClientCon,
                dbo_person.personname,
                dbo_person.surname,
                dbo_jobstatus.description,
                dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.priority
         FROM   ((((((((dbo_employmenttypes
                        INNER JOIN dbo_jobs
                                ON dbo_employmenttypes.employmenttypeid =
                                  dbo_jobs.employmenttypeid)
                       INNER JOIN dbo_clients
                               ON dbo_jobs.clientid = dbo_clients.clientid)
                      INNER JOIN dbo_clientcontacts
                              ON dbo_jobs.clientcontactid =
                                 dbo_clientcontacts.clientcontactid)
                     LEFT JOIN dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns
                            ON dbo_jobs.jobid =
dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.jobid)
                    INNER JOIN dbo_person
                            ON dbo_clientcontacts.contactpersonid =
                   dbo_person.personid)
                   LEFT JOIN dbo_jobconsultants
                          ON dbo_jobs.jobid = dbo_jobconsultants.jobid)
                  LEFT JOIN dbo_users
                         ON dbo_jobconsultants.userid = dbo_users.userid)
                 LEFT JOIN dbo_jobstatus
                        ON dbo_jobs.statusid = dbo_jobstatus.jobstatusid)
                LEFT JOIN dbo_locations
                       ON dbo_jobs.locationid = dbo_locations.locationid
         WHERE  ( ( ( dbo_jobs.archived ) = 'N' )
                  AND ( ( dbo_employmenttypes.employmenttypeid ) <> 12 )
                  AND ( ( dbo_jobconsultants.userrelationshipid ) = 9 )
                  AND
         ( ( dbo_jobstatus.description ) <> 'Filled'
           AND ( dbo_jobstatus.description ) <> 'Filled - Ongoing' ) )) AS
        AllJobs
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT dbo_reviewlists.jobid,
                           Count(dbo_reviewlistapplicants.reviewlistid) AS
                           CountOfRevIDs
                    FROM   dbo_reviewlists
                           LEFT JOIN dbo_reviewlistapplicants
                                  ON dbo_reviewlists.reviewlistid =
                                     dbo_reviewlistapplicants.reviewlistid
                    GROUP  BY dbo_reviewlists.jobid) AS RevListCount
                ON AllJobs.jobid = RevListCount.jobid)
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT dbo_applicantactions.jobid,
                          Count(dbo_applicantactions.statusid) AS CVSentCount
                   FROM   dbo_applicantactions
                   WHERE  (( ( dbo_applicantactions.statusid ) = 29 ))
                   GROUP  BY dbo_applicantactions.jobid) AS CVCount
               ON AllJobs.jobid = CVCount.jobid)
ORDER  BY dbo_jobs.jobid DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given an alias name to your outermost query block, and you are trying to order by dbo_Jobs.JobId instead of alias_name.JobId

(Either that, or your bracket between the group by and order by clauses is not needed - I lost count of the brackets!)

Answer (score 0):

Holy extraneous parenthesis, Batman! This should work. Looks like you needed the outer table alias of `AllJobs` applied to the columns of the outer select statement. I also cleaned up all the unnecessary parenthesis.

```
SELECT
    AllJobs.jobid
    ,AllJobs.jobrefno
    ,AllJobs.createdon
    ,AllJobs.archived
    ,AllJobs.published
    ,AllJobs.jobtitle
    ,AllJobs.statusid
    ,AllJobs.clientid
    ,AllJobs.company
    ,AllJobs.clientcontactid
    ,AllJobs.employmenttypeid
    ,AllJobs.description
    ,AllJobs.description
    ,AllJobs.clientname
    ,AllJobs.natureofcase
    ,AllJobs.timescaletodeadline
    ,AllJobs.notes
    ,AllJobs.status
    ,AllJobs.contactpersonid
    ,AllJobs.vat
    ,AllJobs.postcode
    ,AllJobs.additionalinfo
    ,AllJobs.solicitorref
    ,AllJobs.userid
    ,AllJobs.loginname
    ,AllJobs.positionattributeid
    ,AllJobs.consultancyservice
    ,AllJobs.ClientCon
    ,AllJobs.personname
    ,AllJobs.surname
    ,AllJobs.description
    ,AllJobs.priority
    ,RevListCount.CountOfRevIDs
    ,CVCount.CVSentCount
FROM(
        SELECT
            dbo_jobs.jobid
            ,dbo_jobs.jobrefno
            ,dbo_jobs.createdon
            ,dbo_jobs.archived
            ,dbo_jobs.published
            ,dbo_jobs.jobtitle
            ,dbo_jobs.statusid
            ,dbo_jobs.clientid
            ,dbo_clients.company
            ,dbo_clientcontacts.clientcontactid
            ,dbo_employmenttypes.employmenttypeid
            ,dbo_employmenttypes.description
            ,dbo_locations.description
            ,dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.clientname
            ,dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.natureofcase
            ,dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.timescaletodeadline
            ,dbo_jobs.notes
            ,dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.status
            ,dbo_clientcontacts.contactpersonid
            ,dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.vat
            ,dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.postcode
            ,dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.additionalinfo
            ,dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.solicitorref
            ,dbo_jobconsultants.userid
            ,dbo_users.loginname
            ,dbo_jobs.positionattributeid
            ,dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.consultancyservice
            ,[dbo_person].[personname] & ' ' & [dbo_person].[surname] AS ClientCon
            ,dbo_person.personname
            ,dbo_person.surname
            ,dbo_jobstatus.description
            ,dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.priority
        FROM dbo_employmenttypes
        INNER JOIN dbo_jobs ON dbo_employmenttypes.employmenttypeid = dbo_jobs.employmenttypeid
        INNER JOIN dbo_clients ON dbo_jobs.clientid = dbo_clients.clientid
        INNER JOIN dbo_clientcontacts ON dbo_jobs.clientcontactid = dbo_clientcontacts.clientcontactid
        LEFT JOIN dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns ON dbo_jobs.jobid = dbo_jobsectordefinedcolumns.jobid
        INNER JOIN dbo_person ON dbo_clientcontacts.contactpersonid = dbo_person.personid
        LEFT JOIN dbo_jobconsultants ON dbo_jobs.jobid = dbo_jobconsultants.jobid
        LEFT JOIN dbo_users ON dbo_jobconsultants.userid = dbo_users.userid
        LEFT JOIN dbo_jobstatus ON dbo_jobs.statusid = dbo_jobstatus.jobstatusid
        LEFT JOIN dbo_locations ON dbo_jobs.locationid = dbo_locations.locationid
        WHERE dbo_jobs.archived = 'N'
            AND dbo_employmenttypes.employmenttypeid <> 12
            AND dbo_jobconsultants.userrelationshipid = 9
            AND (
                    dbo_jobstatus.description <> 'Filled'
                    AND dbo_jobstatus.description <> 'Filled - Ongoing'
                )
    )      AS AllJobs
LEFT JOIN(
             SELECT
                 dbo_reviewlists.jobid
                 ,COUNT(dbo_reviewlistapplicants.reviewlistid) AS CountOfRevIDs
             FROM dbo_reviewlists
             LEFT JOIN dbo_reviewlistapplicants ON dbo_reviewlists.reviewlistid = dbo_reviewlistapplicants.reviewlistid
             GROUP BY dbo_reviewlists.jobid
         ) AS RevListCount ON AllJobs.jobid = RevListCount.jobid
LEFT JOIN(
             SELECT
                 dbo_applicantactions.jobid
                 ,COUNT(dbo_applicantactions.statusid) AS CVSentCount
             FROM dbo_applicantactions
             WHERE dbo_applicantactions.statusid = 29
             GROUP BY dbo_applicantactions.jobid
         ) AS CVCount ON AllJobs.jobid = CVCount.jobid
ORDER BY AllJobs.jobid DESC;
```